# Quantum improvement in collision-free ID assignment problem?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

Consider the following: you are a network device that is in charge of assigning unique identifiers (consisting of $b$ bits) to new devices as they join the network. However, you do not have very much persistent memory. In particular, you $k < b$ bits of persistent memory. This means that although there are $2^b$ unique identifiers, you cannot *reliably* assign unique identifiers to $2^b$ different devices, since you would need $b$ bits of memory to keep track of which identifiers you've assigned so far.

However, you can make use of randomness to help reduce the risk of collisions. For instance, if $b=2$ and $k=0$, you could assign identifiers to new devices by choosing their bits randomly. In this case, there is a probability of $3/32\approx 0.09375$ that you will successfully assign $4$ IDs without collisions. However, if $k=1$, you can repeatedly toggle your single bit of memory to achieve a success probability of as high as $1/4 = 0.25$.

**My question:** does quantum computation offer an advantage in this problem? That is, if I am allowed $k < b$ *qubits* of persistent memory rather than $k$ *classical* bits of persistent memory, can I achieve a higher probability of a collision-free assignment? This question has left me completely stumped, and I would be delighted just to see an answer to the simple $b=2, k=1$ case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure any number higher than 25% for $b=2,k=1$ would violate the [Holevo bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holevo%27s_theorem). At most $n$ bits of information can be extracted from $n$ qubits. See if you can prove that this is the case. Assume you have a construction that succeeds 30% of the time, and try to use it to store and retrieve too many bits of information.